# El formulario no registra, hay más código pero este es el que registra, no agregué una sección de roles pero no agrega

Tags: php, formularios

El código no registra, todos los campos están bien, no se que hacer. Hay 2 códigos mas que registra pero no se. Puedo proporcionar la BD y los otros archivos, las tablas están bien, todo está bien según yo.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO t_usuarios (nombre, fechaNacimiento, email, usuario, password, rol) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
$query = $conexion->prepare($sql);
$query->bind_param('ssssss', $datos['nombre'], $datos['fechaNacimiento'], $datos['email'], $datos['usuario'], $datos['password'], $datos['rol']);
$exito = $query->execute();
$query->close();
return $exito ? 1 : 0; // Éxito al agregar o fallo al agregar
```

Comment: que significa no registra? cual es el valor de la variable $exito?  si algo no functiona debes proporcionar detalles sobre en que punto falla. Debes debugar el codigo y ver linea por linea si se ejecuta correctamente.